# como saber si vector esta ordenado

Tags: c, vectores, números-enteros

Esta es la consigna y como lo resolvi:

> Programe una funcion que recibe un vector v de numeros enteros,
> y su longitud n, y devuelve 1 si esta ordenado (ya sea creciente o
> decrecientemente), y 0 si no.

> Ejemplo:
> `{1,1,2}` esta ordenado en forma ascendente y retorna 1, `{6,4}` esta ordenado en forma descendente y retorna 1, `{1,3,2}` esta desordenado y retorna 0.

me gustaria saber si con este codigo esta resuelta la consigna:

```
int ordenado(int v[], int n){
   //Escribir aca el codigo de la funcion ordenado
   int i, ordenado;
   ordenado= v[0];
   for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(v[i] < ordenado && v[i] > ordenado )
           return 1;
        else
           return 0;        
   }
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: No entiendo esta pregunta ... es tan fácil como probarlo, ¿ no ?

Comment: si pero no se como probarlo es decir como llamar a la funcion

Comment: 1) No resuelve tu consigna, siempre se escapa del for a la primera iteración y el primer if es siempre falso a menos que sean iguales. 2) Debes poder probar tu código eso es lo primero, tienes que empezar por ahí obligatoriamente

Comment: No va a funcionar por varios motivos, al menos tres: 1) haces una comparación con `<` en vez de `<=` (el array [1,1,2] fallará incluso cuando está ordenado); 2) devuelves el valor después de la primera comparación (deberías devolver valor sólo si es erróneo); y 3) nunca actualizas el valor de `ordenado`, por lo que siempre se estará comparando con el primer elemento (el array [1,4,2,3] dirá que está ordenado cuando no lo está). Cómo dicen los demás, deberías probar tu función, me imagino que lo que necesitas son casos de prueba que cubran lo máximo posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recapitulando los problemas principales mencionados en los comentarios:

- La condición del if siempre será **falsa**. Es imposible que un número sea mayor y menor a otro simultáneamente.
- La condición del if tampoco tiene en cuenta el caso ordenado en el que hay 2 elementos iguales.
- La ejecución deja la función en el primer ciclo. En ambos casos del if hay un return. Por lo tanto no hay posibilidad de que el ciclo se repita.

Sugiero que te enfoques en verificar un orden a la vez. Puedes hacer una función que verifique si está ordenado ascendentemente y otra decrecientemente.

Luego, puedes elegir que hacer según el resultado de ejecutar ambas funciones con el mismo arreglo.

Por ejemplo:

```
int ordenCreciente(int v[], int n){
   for (int i = 0, max = n - 1; i < max; i++){
        if(!(v[i] <= v[i + 1]))
           return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}

int ordenDecreciente(int v[], int n){
   for (int i = 0, max = n - 1; i < max; i++){
        if(!(v[i] >= v[i + 1]))
           return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}

int ordenado(int v[], int n){
     return ordenCreciente(v, n) || ordenDecreciente(v, n);
}
```

Me parece conveniente demostrar el orden por contraposición lógica porque es más simple:

- Si el arreglo no está ordenado significa que al menos dos pares de elementos no cumplen la condición.
- Si no se encuentra nigún par, entonces el arreglo está ordenado.

Puedes probar el código [aquí](https://tio.run/##tZBBTsMwEEX3PsUnbBLFRXVDJSBpWcAaDhCyiBwHLFEHmTRCanP2MA4hrVqQkCqsWYz/vBn/sZw8S9l159rI13WhkLzXha4uXpaMaVOjsoUyd1ZJrUytfCc1acbhEhNsGICysugLGgtMOVb5ByUGE4iYtMQJlIThF94fXfpnfpPqDMmCBmqEEFkQjHU6VtVrazCNndiynSJi1u6Zu1fyH@0tT7WXF9WPtkb@4IcbTgS22@Pl@so4fJVr4w@j3D23VqQZbbaB4C5mHBHaeB@YDcA1xxXHvA9xwES7IYRdUnwDb5aQ0h@3ci9SOcAtvMdBfDIebuA9VOPypAS/9pPH@Sn90V/fb7vuEw).

Answer (score 0):

encuentro varios errores en tú código:

1. Ordenado siempre tendrá el mismo valor, por ende la comparación no será efectiva.
2. En el if, estás "preguntando" si la posición x del vector es menor que "ordenado" y al mismo tiempo mayor, lo cual siempre da FALSE y nunca tendrás un return 1.

Esta es la solución que yo te propondría:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//función
int ordenado(int v[], int n)
{  
  int tipo = 0;
 
  if(v[0] <= v[n-1])
  {
    //evaluar ascendente
    for( int i = 0 ; i < (n-1) ; i++)
    {  //1234565
      if(v[i] <= v[i+1])
      {
        printf("%i vs %i tipo 1 \n",v[i],v[i+1]);
        tipo = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        printf("%i vs %i tipo 0 \n",v[i],v[i+1]);
        tipo = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    return tipo;
  }
  else if(v[0] >= v[n-1])
  {
    //evaluar descendente
    for( int i = 0 ; i < (n-1) ; i++)
    {  //654321
      if(v[i] >= v[i+1])
      {
        printf("%i vs %i tipo 1 \n",v[i],v[i+1]);
        tipo = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        printf("%i vs %i tipo 0 \n",v[i],v[i+1]);
        tipo = 0;
        break;
      }
   
    }
    return tipo;
  }
  else
  {
    //evaluar desordenado
   
    tipo = 0;
    return tipo;
  }
}

int main(void) {

  int n = 10;
  
  int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};//arreglo ord ascendente
  int d[10] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};//arreglo ord descendente
  int e[10] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,8,1};//arreglo desordenado
  
  int resultado = ordenado(a,n);
  printf("vector ascendente: %i \n \n",resultado);

  
  resultado = ordenado(d,n);
  printf("vector descendente: %i \n \n", resultado);

  
  resultado = ordenado(e,n);
  printf("vector desordenado: %i \n \n", resultado);
  return 0;
  
}
```

Primero, se compara la primera posición del vector para ver si aplicaremos el procedimiento ascendente, descendente o desordenado. Luego vamos comparando posición 1 vs posición 2 en un loop de duración "n".

Quedo al pendiente para cualquier duda, saludos!